# Server 2012 - migrate roaming profiles to user profile disks

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012

I have a Windows Server 2012 based environment wich includes a small RDS farm (1 broker 3 session hosts). They did not not have "user profile disks" enabled when set up. I'm currently evaluating the possibilities to change this. One thing not clear for me is: How can I migrate the existing "classic" roaming profiles (about 200) to userprofiles disks? I did find a lot of information on how to set UPD's up in a new environment but no information on how to *migrate*. Can someone give me a pointer on this maybe? 
Thanks in advance, dura

Answer (score 0):

Set the PD up and copy the profiles over to the new disk:

```
robocopy /MIR /R:1 /W:1 /B /SEC /COPYALL /MT:64 /XJ <source> <destination>
```

Comment: But I would have to do this manually for each user? - Logon user so his Disk gets created -> log off user -> copy profile to UPD -> next user?

Comment: If done via GPO not - the Logon will move the profile ("move to news location ..."). If done via copy, you'd have to. If you use one destination for alle your profiles, you can copy all at once.